# Trade external access token for local one - ASP.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

When using ASP.Net Identity and retrieving an external access token from an external provider, how do I then trade-in/issue a local access token using the external access token?

I've seen `[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]` but have not been able to get it working on my action method. If I send with headers

```
 Authentication: Bearer external_access_token
```

It does not populate the `User.Identity`

Startup.Auth.cs:

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/AccountApi/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    });
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

Comment: I see the mistake you're making. The 3rd party token is of no use to you. Use the user ID you get back. Make an association with an application user in your Identity the 1st time the user registers the 3rd party, from then on use that user ID to login locally and generate a local bearer token.

Comment: I'm not following. What does [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)] do? Look at this method: https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.API/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L175

It uses the access token to make an api call to respective provider and fetch the user id and then issues a local access token. I'm looking to replace this API-calling code, I thought thats what the above attribute is for.

Comment: I can access the UserId from OnAuthenticated callback however, this is a separate api call I'm not using cookies to preseve the identity in between api calls. On the second call all I have is an external access token, is there a way to leverage Identity framework to retrieve the user id without manual api calls?

Comment: That library authenticates a user based on a bearer token created by **ASP.NET**. But you cannot automatically "Trade external access token for local one". It's like trading an Australian Dollar for a US Dollar. Yes, the standard is the same, the token gives your app no information about the user. A G+ or FB token is only good for making calls to their API.

Comment: When you get the auth confirmation from 3rd party, they usually create a local cookie with claims. You analyze those claims to find the user's ID for 3rd party app and their name / email. Then, check if the user exists in your Identity DB. If the user does not exist, create a new entry. If the user does exist, return to UI a new bearer token.

Comment: Correct, I do most of that except I dont return the new bearer token right away. Instead I return the external access token and would like to make a second api call to obtain a local access token. I guess this is not really possible to do in separate api calls without complicating it with external api calls. It would normally work with cookies since the cookie would get saved on the browser and sent on the subsequent call, but not without.

Comment: hmmm, seems like a wasted round trip. Why not return both: Your new access token AND the 3rd party token along with provider name? If you did need to follow that work flow, it becomes difficult. API's don't have sessions by default. So, you would need to store the external bearer token  for future reference on the server. Seems excessive. I tend to skip a step and do my 3rd party authentication using JS. I keep the external token AND cookie, and then send the user-id to my Account API to return a bearer token. This is more work, though.

Comment: Well because thats the external login redirect uri so all that info gets returned in the url, I was worried returning both access tokens and other info for 'associate' view (first time registers) would overflow the allowed url chars. The access tokens are quite long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82419/discussion-between-dave-alperovich-and-parliament).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow of **OWIN Middleware** External Authentication involves

- Redirecting / querying External **OAuth Provider**
- Registering new user with **ASP.NET Identity** using the External Cookie and all claims information
- Returning a Bearer Token to the *Presentation Layer*.

---

The **`[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]`** is not used to allow *External Bearer Tokens* to be used in-place of local authority Bearer Tokens. *External Bearer Tokens* are only used to Authenticate the user's Identity.

**OWIN Middleware** Authentication should always conclude with an **OWIN Middleware** Bearer Token returned to the user. Whether the User Authenticates with a local Login/Password or with External Authentication Cookie / Token, the user must get a local authority Token to make use of Secure Methods.

If the user does not exist in your *Identity Database* after External Authentication, Register the user and return a new Bearer Token.

Comment: Hello @dave-alperovich, after getting externalLogin FromIdentity (External Cookie set by FB), What to do when you found the user exists/ not-exists in identity DB (GetExternalLogin action in web-api). Can you please refer some code.

Comment: How to receive Bearer Token from web-api to client if web-api authenticated with External Login?